# behavior of org.hibernate.lockmode.pessimistic_write

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two services that are invoked at about same time with id = 1. Service1 starts first, then Service2. However Service2 finishes first before Service1. What should be the expected Values of variable myClass  after both are are finished (assume initial color is "BLUE" and height= 5)? Is it

1. myClass has color "GREEN", height 5
2. myClass has height 12, color "BLUE"
3. or myClass has color "GREEN" and height 12 ?

Here are my Classes:

```
class Service1{

 private MyDao myDao;

 public void method1(Integer id){
   MyClass myClass = myDao.get(MyClass.class,id,LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
   //change myClass
    myClass.setColor("GREEN");
   update(myClass);
 }
}

class Service2{

 private MyDao myDao;

 public void method2(Integer id){
   MyClass myClass = myDao.get(MyClass.class,id,LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
   //different change in change myClass
   myClass.setHeight(12);
   update(myClass);
 }
}

class MyDao{
  public Object get(Class clazz, Serializable id, LockMode mode){
   return getHibernateTemplate().get(clazz,id,mode);

 }
}
```

Here I am particalary interested in the behavior of PESSIMISTIC_WRITE. My actual code is written with spring and I am tracing a particular problem wherein an update is not invoked. My suspect is that it is due to PESSIMISTIC_WRITE but I am now sure that's why I want confirm it's behavior.

Answer (score 4):

**What is Pessimitic Locking?**
-Pessimistic locking is an approach where an entity is locked until the transaction of that entity is finished. A lock can either limits or prevents other user form working with that entity in the database. 

**Scope of Lock**
-A scope of lock might be

- the entire database (database lock),
- a table (table lock),
- a collection of rows (page locks) or
- a single row (row locks).

**Different Lock Mode in Pessimistic**

From [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-locking).

```
LockMode.WRITE is acquired automatically when Hibernate updates or inserts a row.
LockMode.UPGRADE can be acquired upon explicit user request using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE on databases which support that syntax.
LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT can be acquired upon explicit user request using a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT under Oracle.
LockMode.READ is acquired automatically when Hibernate reads data under Repeatable Read or Serializable isolation level. It can be re-acquired by explicit user request.
LockMode.NONE represents the absence of a lock. All objects switch to this lock mode at the end of a Transaction. Objects associated with the session via a call to update() or saveOrUpdate() also start out in this lock mode.
```

Now in your situation, no.2 will be the value, if it first execute. Then other update will be disallow. Remember that a `LockMode.WRITE` is acquired automatically after it was requested, this indicates that the current holder of the lock (which is the myClass in method2) intends to update the entity in your situation it locks the row. Then it will disallow anyone (myClass in method1) to read, update and delete the entity.

Hope it was clear.

Comment: will it throw an exception then?

Comment: as from my experience, Pessimistic write doesn't throw an exception. If your looking at org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException, this was for optimistic locking.

Comment: as I test, I confirmed it doesn't throw any exception, but logging select and update. You should create a test to see.